# NSNotificationCenter not working when MBProgressHub is running in Main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter, mbprogresshud

I'm working with the `NSNotificationCenter`. Problem is on button click i have show the `MBProgressHUB` till  45 Seconds, In between this if server do any changes `NSNotificationCenter` is not triggers.

If i don't use the `MBProgressHub` the notification triggers. Below is the code which I have implemented.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^() {

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MqttResponseNotification" object:message.payloadString];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MqttResponseHomeScreenNotification" object:message.payloadString];
});
```

the NSNotificationCenter inside  the dispatch_Async are not tigger whenMBProgressHub is running.

Please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

First you register object for `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidLoad` Or `ViewWillApper` method like below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MqttResponseHomeScreenNotification Method:) name:@"MqttResponseHomeScreenNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void) MqttResponseHomeScreenNotification Method:(NSNotification *) notification {
}
```

Comment: this is done , my problem is it works fine with with out MBProgressHub,

Comment: can you please add MBProgressHub like [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:hud];

Comment: also try
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^()
   {

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(CallNotification) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});

-(void) CallNotification {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"MqttResponseNotification"
         object:message.payloadString];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"MqttResponseHomeScreenNotification"
         object:message.payloadString];

}